# The number of ways a coin can be tossed 6 times so that there is exactly 3 heads and no two heads occur in a row is?

Tags: probability

I am trying to figure out the problem below.

The number of ways a coin can be tossed 6 times so that there is exactly  3 heads and no two heads  occur in a row is?

At first it seemed like it would just be .5•.5•.5•.5•.5•.5 which would be 0.015625, since none of the outcomes are dependent on each other.  Then as I was reading the question more carefully, I thought maybe the answer is 2?  Since there are only 2 outcomes for each toss?

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The **number of ways**" will result in an integer, not a number between $0$ and $1$ (exclusive).  "The **probability**" will result in a number between $0$ and $1$ (inclusive), but never a number larger than $1$.  The phrasing of the question you posted is "The number of ways."

Comment: I see, that makes sense.  Can you by chance tell me how to calculate it?  Not sure where to go with this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question asks for "The *number of ways*" that you can flip six coins with exactly 3 heads and 3 tails such that no two heads appear next to one another.

Use the tails as a barrier:

$$\underline{~}T\underline{~}T\underline{~}T\underline{~}$$

The three heads may go into those four available spaces with at most one head per space.  Choose which three spaces are occupied.

> Four spaces, you want to choose three of them, there are then $\binom{4}{3}=4$ different such sequences. The sequences are specifically HTHTHT, HTHTTH, HTTHTH, THTHTH

---

As an aside, the probability of this happening is: The number of ways it could happen / The total number of ways of flipping coins regardless of this happening.

> $\frac{4}{2^6} = \frac{1}{2^4} = \frac{1}{16}$

Comment: Gotcha!  I see where I went wrong.  Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually 4:

$$(T, H, T, H, T, H)$$
$$(H, T, T, H, T, H)$$
$$(H, T, H, T, T, H)$$
$$(H, T, H, T, H, T)$$

Comment: Thank you!  This is an excellent way to visualize it

Answer (score 1):

HTHTHT

HTHTTH

HTTHTH

THTHTH

Number of WAYS = 4

Probability of this occurring =$\frac{4}{2^6}$ = $\frac{1}{16}$